# +300 warnings in Xcode from Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, xcode8, il2cpp

I made Build my App for iOS with 'Unity version: 5.4.1f1 (64 bit)', then open Project with 'Xcode version: 8.2.1 (8C1002)' no exist Warnings and Errors, but launch RUN Build and view 329 Warnings, in summary:

```
Unused function 'InitCrash' -> CrashReporter.mm
Unused function 'InitObjCUEHandler' -> CrashReporter.mm
Unused variable 'iBound' -> mscorlib_ArrayTypes.h
Undeclared selector 'onUnityUpdateViewLayout' -> UnityView.mm
Undeclared selector 'createUnityViewImpl' -> UnityAppcontroller.mm
Undeclared selector 'createViewHierarchyImpl' -> UnityAppcontroller.mm
Code will never be executed:
    Bulk_Generics_0.cpp
    Bulk_Generics_1.cpp
    Bulk_Generics_2.cpp
    Bulk_Generics_3.cpp
    GenericMethods0.cpp
'extern' variable has an initializer -> Il2CppCompilerCalculateTypeValues.cpp
```

How do I fix or remove these warnings of Xcode?

Please help me!

J

Comment: As long as there are only warnings and no errors you're fine, there's nothing to "fix". In fact I'd rather not touch any of the Unity generated code at all. If the Unity code generates an error that shouldn't exist then that's a different scenario.

Comment: Thank you Keiwan, I was worried so many warnings.